# UiTextField not changing after Prepare for Segue

Tags: xcode, swift, uitextfield, segue

I am having a strange little problem when I segue to the next ViewController. I have it set up so that when I segue it should change the TextField of the next ViewController but for some reason or another it isn't. The segue works but the TextField doesn't change.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Edit" {
        let cell = sender as! UITableViewCell
        let indexPath = TaskTableViews.indexPathForCell(cell)
        let itemController: TaskManager = segue.destinationViewController as! TaskManager
        let nItem: List = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! List
        itemController.nItem = nItem
    }
    if (segue.identifier == "Give") {
        let itemController : TaskManager = segue.destinationViewController as! TaskManager
        itemController.addTaskText = "Great"

    }

}
```

Heres the ViewDidLoad of my secondViewController..

```
// View Did Load
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if nItem != nil {
        addTask.text = (nItem?.taskName)!
        }

    addTask.placeholder = "Title ..."
    addTaskText = addTask.text!
```

Comment: try `viewDidAppear`?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you're actually performing the segue with the relevant identifier and take a look at prepareForSegue. If it is like the code below it should work. Also, in your second ViewController you can set the text in your textField in viewDidLoad. Just make sure that the data is actually being passed from the first to the second ViewController

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "Great" {

        let itemController = segue.destinationViewController as! YourDestinationViewController
        itemController.someStringVariable = "Great"
    }

}
```

In your second ViewController you can declare a variable that will get it's value during the segue and then use that variable's value to set the text of your textField, like this:

```
var someStringVariable: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Check if the value has been set to your string and if it has set it to be the textField's text
    if someStringVariable != nil {

        textField.text = someStringVariable
    }
}
```

Comment: Its so strange, the segue works because Ive used a Print"..." and it works. I think the data just totally resets no matter what after the segue.